# mysql driver not found copying into tomcat7/lib

Tags: mysql, tomcat, tomcat7, driver

I´m deploying a simple java application in a raspbian with tomcat 7 and I'm having troubles with the mysql jdbc driver:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I have read that copying the jar into tomcat7/lib resolved the problem but it doesn´t work.

I let you a "screen" of my /usr/share/tomcat7/lib (It is the correct folder?)

```
pi@raspberrypi **/usr/share/tomcat7/lib** $ ls -al mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 968670 Jul  9 08:47 mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
```

After that, I have done a sudo chmod 777 and copy again the war file to the webapp and nothing.

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: That ought to work. Do you also have the driver in your web app's `WEB-INF/lib` directory? It shouldn't matter, but you should make sure that it doesn't appear twice in the `ClassLoader`.

Comment: I have nothing into my exported .war (WEB-INF\lib). ¿I´m exporting wrong the project? On Eclipse I do: File, export, WAR file, and mark "Export source files".

Comment: Have you actually checked your WAR file to see what's inside of it?